# Aggregate multiple rows N+1 queries with row counting

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have an N+1 problem I would like to efficiently solve. I've got N such queries where I would like to set offsets, limits and count found rows(limits and offsets are same across all queries):

```
students table:
    |-----------|----------|-----------|
    |     id    |   name   |   group   |
    |-----------|----------|-----------|
    | 1         | Bob      | groupA    |
    |-----------|----------|-----------|
    | 2         | Fred     | groupB    |
    |-----------|----------|-----------|
    | 3         | Bill     | groupB    |
    |-----------|----------|-----------|
    | 4         | Joe      | groupC    |
    |-----------|----------|-----------|
    | 5         | Bob      | groupB    |
    |-----------|----------|-----------|
    | 6         | Mark     | groupB    |
    |-----------|----------|-----------|
    | 7         | Will     | groupC    |
    |-----------|----------|-----------|
    | 8         | Tom      | groupD    |
    |-----------|----------|-----------|

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, name 
FROM students 
WHERE group = 'groupA' 
ORDER BY name 
LIMIT 3;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as count;

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, name 
FROM students 
WHERE group = 'groupB'
ORDER BY name 
LIMIT 3;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as count;

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, name 
FROM students 
WHERE group = 'groupC'
ORDER BY name 
LIMIT 3;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as count;

    ...and so on
```

Is there an efficient way to aggregate this queries and perform them against my DB so it wont cause high load and resolve fast with large amount of rows and groups?

At the output of such aggregated query I would like to receive a data set for each of the selected group with applied LIMIT and total rows for that group count

Comment: I don't understand what this code is supposed to be doing, which is why sample data and desired results are so helpful.

Comment: Do you have `row_number()` on your MySQL platform?

Comment: Looks like it's not easy possible to aggregate these queries onto one query because `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`  counts beyond the `LIMIT`... But hard to suggest something without table structure, example data and expected output.

Comment: Combining multiple distinct queries into one is possible via union, but execution will not be faster than executing the queries separately